# CoreData merging data from two different contexts

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am updating my core data in a background thread. I've setup the policy. THe updater class updates and saves the data.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *defaultContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[defaultContext persistentStoreCoordinator]];
        [context setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];               //step 2
        [defaultContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy];

        Updater *updater = [[Updater alloc] initWithUsername:@"test2" 
                                                    password:@"test2"];
        [updater setContext:context];
        [updater update];
        [updater release];

        [self setUpdating:NO];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completion();
        });
    });
```

My friend told me that i need some sort of notification to notify my original default context to update the data. Do I need that? Or what I have done will suffice? If so, how would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to observe NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification in order to merge those two contexts.

I recognize from "//step 2" that you've seen article [CORE DATA AND THREADS, WITHOUT THE HEADACHE](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/) so I'd suggest that you review it again, and [necessary code](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/Source/Categories/NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalRecord.m) for notification observation is referenced in this article also.